# How to escape quotations marks in a hyperlink

Tags: php

The link I must get to must be http://localhost:8088/imageInfo.php?id=4
 I started with this and no matter how I tried to escape I couldn't do it so any help would be appreciated

```
."<a href='imageInfo.php?id=<?php echo $image_id;?>'>".
```

Comment: `echo` inside `echo`? Are you sure what are you doing?

Comment: Maybe just `<a href="imageInfo.php?id=<?php echo $image_id;?>">` ?  Why is the whole line in quotes with leading and trailing periods?  That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It should be html code and should not be echoed again

```
 <a href='imageInfo.php?id=<?php echo $image_id;?>'>Image Link</a>
```

Or,

```
 "<a href='imageInfo.php?id=". $image_id ."'>Image Link</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this snippet perhaps part of a larger line of code?  Something like this?:

```
echo "some string" . "<a href='imageInfo.php?id=<?php echo $image_id;?>'>" . "another string";
```

If so then the problem has nothing to do with the quotes, the problem is that you're echoing PHP code *as a string* to the response.  The browser isn't going to know what to do with that PHP code.  Instead, just concatenate the values you have into a single string.  Something like:

```
echo 'some string<a href="imageInfo.php?id=' . $image_id . '">another string';
```

(Note that I also swapped single quotes and double quotes so that the resulting HTML is using double quotes.  While either one works, technically HTML attributes should be double-quoted.)

Basically, you don't need to embed PHP code *in PHP code*.  You're already in the context of executing PHP, just execute the code right there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put your HTML code in the echo, you can just regard these HTML code as string and use . to connect them together with your phone variables.

```
echo "<a href='imageInfo.php?id=".$image_id."'>LINK</a>";
```